# iOS compare NSUInteger to NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to compare to numeric values to each other but I get the warning "Comparison of integers of different signs: 'NSInteger' (aka 'inti) and 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int').

Which is logical since I do that ;). But how do I fix this warning. This is the code that raises the warning:

```
if (page >= self.controllers.count || page < 0)
    return;
```

Page can be -1 so it is a NSInteger but count returns a NSUInteger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using an NSInteger for page and -1, use NSUInteger and NSNotFound where you use -1.

Then you're comparing the same types.

```
if (page >= self.controllers.count || page == NSNotFound)
    return;
```

Comment: So when I pass -1 I should pass NSNotFound. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You're using -1 to indicate no page. Instead use NSNotFound.

Comment: I just checked when I pass -1 it automatically is NSNotFound is this true?

Comment: @MouNtant you are trying to set the value of a NSUInteger to -1 which is probably why you're getting NSNotFound because that isn't a valid operation. However, it may work now but may not in the future. Best to return NSNotFound explicitly if that is what you're checking for.

Comment: Not exactly, but sort of. If you pass a negative number to an unsigned variable it will loop around. NSNotFound may be defined as NSIntegerMax (which is what -1 might loop around to), but that's not guaranteed. So pass NSNotFound and you'll be safe if a later version of the OS changes what NSNotFound is defined as.